# Does AutoIT work WIth Mocha Selenium, Nodejs ,Javascript for windows Authtication

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automation, mocha.js, autoit

I am automating an Application where when we click on button pop up for windows Authentication, i am using selenium, mocha, javascript for automation
please help me  -- how to authenticate by automation

i tried with AutoIT, it starts the AutoIT exe but not not able to enter userid password

Please help

*Edit*
**AutoIT Script**

```
WinWaitActive("Authentication Required") 
Send("userid") 
Send("{TAB}") 
Send("password") 
Send("{ENTER}")
```

**Edit**
Test Code

```
  var testAuthencation =function(){ console.log("Auth started");
     var workerProcess = child_process.execFile('C:/AutoITScript/AutoITScrippt.exe', function(error, stdout, stderr)
     { if(error)
 { console.log("Error stack :: " + error.stack);
 console.log("Error code :: " + error.code); console.log("Signal :: " + error.signal);
 } console.log("stdout :: " + stdout);
 console.log("stderr :: " + stderr); }); workerProcess.on('exit',function(code){ console.log('CHild process exited :: Code :: ' + code) });
     }
```

Comment: Can you share your autoIT script? As long as you running on windows, autoIT should work.

Comment: WinWaitActive("Authentication Required")
Send("userid")
Send("{TAB}")
Send("password")
Send("{ENTER}")

Comment: This question is still missing crucial information, and is therefore off-topic. You've shown the code you use to start AutoIT but you've not shown the context in which it is used. How is your Mocha test structured? Also, you've not told us what you get on the console. You've got a bunch of `console.log`. **Do they output anything??** This is useful to know. Also, did you try just starting AutoIT outside of a Mocha test, did it work? Adding a [mcve] to your question and describing the results you get would make your question acceptable for the site.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the title for authentication window on your browser. Adding bit improved code for autoIT script for answer as it is not fit for comments section.

```
WinWaitActive("","Authentication Required","120")
 If WinExists("","Authentication Required") Then
 Send("username{TAB}")
 Send("password{Enter}")
 EndIf
```

Here I am trying to identify text present inside authentication dialog in case title is not recognized.

Give it a try.

Comment: i tried this but still not able to enter userid and password, may be i dont know mocha supports AutoIT scripts or not ? if you have selenium code in nodejs javscript  can you post it for me

Comment: How you are invoking autoitscript.exe? I tried to answer this question for Autoit tag. Sorry I have not tried mocha , nodejs javascript and selenium combination. :( Please post your test code also, so that someone else can help you out better.

Comment: var testAuthencation =function(){
   console.log("Auth started");
   var workerProcess = child_process.execFile('C:/AutoITScript/AutoITScrippt.exe', function(error, stdout, stderr) {  
        if(error) {
   console.log("Error stack :: " + error.stack);
   console.log("Error code :: " + error.code);
   console.log("Signal :: " + error.signal);
  }
  console.log("stdout :: " + stdout);
  console.log("stderr :: " + stderr);
    }); 
 workerProcess.on('exit',function(code){
  console.log('CHild process exited :: Code :: ' + code)
 });
}

Comment: I am using given above code for the same but not able to enter user id and password, exe is executing fine  which i can seen in Windows process, but not able to enter userid and password, when i try this exe with java its working fine but not with jaavScript nodejs selenium